# useInfiniteQuery but all the data re-rendered every refetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm trying pagination by useInfiniteQuery in React Query, it's refetch data perfectly, but there's a problem that each time new data added, the page re-render all the data list, include existed ones, and it's jump to head of the page, while I want that it's keep fetch and render new data on scroll. I make it as the doc, so can anyone help?
Docs: https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/load-more-infinite-scroll

```
  const { ref, inView } = useInView();

  const { status, data, isFetching, isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage } =
    useInfiniteQuery(["videos", endpoint], getVideo, {
      getNextPageParam: () => 5,
    });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      console.log("Loaded more");
      fetchNextPage();
    }
  }, [inView]);

  return (
    <div className="recommended_videos">
      <h2>Recommended Videos</h2>

      {status === "loading" || isFetching ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : status === "error" ? (
        <div>Error</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="recommended_videos_videos">
          {data?.pages.map((page) =>
            page.data?.items?.map?.((video) => (
              <VideoCard
                video={video}
                id={(video.id.videoId && video.id.videoId) || video.id}
                key={(video.id.videoId && video.id.videoId) || video.id}
              />
            ))
          )}
        </div>
      )}
      <div ref={ref}>
          {isFetchingNextPage ? <Loader /> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Their example is actually doing the same thing as you'r one. The only difference is that their api seems to be fixed and no 'new data' ever comes in

Comment: Why have you passed "videos" and endpoint as an array? They have not done like this in example.

Comment: Yeah I'm testing with a fixed API, but it's still working as new data still added in spite of duplicate, so maybe data is not the problem

Comment: It's how react-query work, I need to pass endpoint to getVideo function, and "videos" is just the key

Comment: Try make a codeSandbox of your issue as that would help alot

Comment: What is that '5' doing everytime on getNextParams - incrementing by 5 everytime?

Comment: `getNextPageParam` is an additional param, in real projects it usually defines next page's index to fetch. In this example I used a dummy one as 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem is here

```
status === "loading" || isFetching ? (<Loader />)
```

Because each time refetch, `isFetching` always turn to `true`, so all the component must be re-rendered.
Actually I removed all this condition, because under data list I used another  
By the way, many thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Many thanks! I spent half a day wonder why structural sharing didn't kick in...