# React re-rendering entire list of items with unique keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-query

I am using the React-Query `useInfiniteQuery` hook to fetch a list of items and display them like this:

```js
{data.pages.map((page) =>
  page.data.map((project) => (
    <Project project={project} key={project.id} />
  )),
)}
```

When I fetch next data (add items to the last) only added items renders which is good.

However, when fetching previous items (they get prepended to the list) all the items are re-rendered.

Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/boring-grass-lt9jvr

I tested without React-Query, just an items state
In this case adding items to the beginning or the end doesn't rerender other items. (https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/exciting-hermann-7sl8cg)

```js
{items.map((project) => (
  <Project project={project} key={project.id} />
)}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm kind of at a loss why the behavior is different between the two sandboxes. Only thing I can think of is that it's either something with Next.js or React-Query, or both. See if you can try regular state in your Next.js sandbox, and try React-Query in your regular sandbox, to see if behavior changes.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223837/useinfinitequery-but-all-the-data-re-rendered-every-refetch

Comment: @DrewReese Well, I'm sure It's not Next.js as I don't have it locally.

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar That's a different problem.